# How can I get Dropbox not to sync a particular folder that doesn't have read permissions?

Tags: macos, sync, encryption, dropbox, encfs

I am using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) 2.4.10 on OS X. I use [Spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29) with an encfs-encrypted folder inside my Dropbox, which is mounted with the `-o local` option to get it to work on OS X 10.9 (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115289/6171)). As a result, Spotlight puts a `.Spotlight-V100` directory inside my encfs-encrypted folder. This directory, and all the files and directories within it, are owned by `root:staff`, which means Dropbox cannot synchronise them (I get an "Access denied" message from Dropbox on the Settings menu).

How can I get Dropbox not to attempt to synchronise this folder, and hence remove this message? Alternatively, is there another way to solve this (mostly cosmetic) problem? Note that the "Selective Sync" feature of Dropbox doesn't work for this problem, as the folder has never been synchronised, so doesn't appear in the list (at least, I think that's the reason).

Comment: The following question proposed a possible solution to your problem.  It seems that`Selective Sync` really should list the folder though.

Comment: Maybe you could create the folder manually first (not mounting it) with the folder you want to ignore, ignore that and then put in the real files. (If the problem is indeed permissions)

Comment: Jozef, good idea. I did a variation of that: paused Dropbox sync, changed the perms to my user on the encfs folder for Spotlight (but not the contents), started Dropbox sync to sync that folder, then went into the Dropbox settings and ignored it using Selective Sync. That seems to be working (including on my other machines, where the folder shows up empty). If you write that up as an answer, I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the folder inside dropbox, it will try to sync it. Create a folder by same name on dropbox website, and on Mac, stop sync of the folder. It wont touch it.

Comment: Sonal, this is similar to Jozef's solution in the comments above also.

Comment: similar, yes. I hope it works for you. If you find some other solution, which is more efficient, please do share with us.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to put everything under a single subfolder, and to hardlink just this internal folder into Dropbox:

1. Move the encrypted folder *outside* of your dropbox. Let's assume it's called `~/enc-folder`.
2. Mount the encfs volume. Let's assume you mount it as `SecureVolume`.
3. Create a sub-folder `SecureVolume/SecureFolder` and notice the name of the corresponding new folder that instantly appears under `enc-folder`. Let's assume it's name is `fgwEGEHeh34`.
4. Move all of the other documents and folders from `SecureVolume` into `SecureFolder` (except of course for the hidden stuff, which is primarily the spotlight folder and your `.encfs6.xml`).
5. Install [hardlink](https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink).
6. Run `hardlink ~/enc-folder/fgwEGEHeh34 ~/Dropbox/fgwEGEHeh34`

You'll now notice the `fgwEGEHeh34` synchronizing perfectly inside your Dropbox with every change in the mounted volume.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: back up the hidden `.encfs6.xml` file since it's required in *addition* to your password to decrypt the files. I personally keep both the hard-linked ugly-named folder and a hard-link to the xml file, under a SecureStuff top-level Dropbox folder.